# Active Record get associated model with polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic address model like so:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

As well as two possible associations, users and friends:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friends, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I would like to be able to get the friends or the user from the address. Both are related to the Address model.

How could I have the following:

```
Address.last.user
```

Or

```
Address.last.friends.first
```

Thank you

Comment: I know it is a little late to say this but it may help someone: Your schema is a little askew. `Address` should not have `Friends`. This is not realistic. Think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Address.new.addressable # will give the addressed object
# Depending what was addressed it will return User or Friend
```

But to achieve this what you ask, you would need to create a method, and it would not be treated as a relation (could not be used in the join)

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true

  def user
    addressable if addressable_type == User.name
  end

  def friend
    addressable if addressable_type == Friend.name
  end
end
```

You can not call relations in class, you have to call them on an object.
`Address.user # will throw an error`

Also `Address` has a relation type `belongs_to` so you do not have a list of friends for address, you have a list of addresses for a friend.

Comment: Is it normal then that by the very same query written using User.find_by(Address.last.addressable_id) is faster than Address.last.user ?

Answer (score 1):

As you defined a polymorphic model.

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**One address will be associated with One instance of either `User` or `Friend`**.

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

> *With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association.*

```
Address.last.user or Address.first.friend
```

Here you defined a relation between address and friend.

```
class Friend < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

so each instance of `Friend` can have multiple instances of `Address` like:

```
Friend.last.addresses # office address, home address
```